# Save a double value from textView to a variable

Tags: java, android, textview, double, reverse-geocoding

I am making a geocoder-reverse geocoder.
The coordinates are generated in a textview which I want to further use in reverse geocoding.
The problem is that the app suddenly stops working when I try to save the contents of textview into the variable.
                                                                         `LATITUDE = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());`
`LATITUDE` being the variable, `t` is the `textView` in which the coordinates are generated.

Is there any other way to save a `double` value from `textView` into a variable so that it can be used further.
If not, can this problem be solved.

Thanks in Advance :)

Here is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button b;
public TextView t;
public TextView u;
public TextView add;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener listener;
public Button b2;
private EditText e;
double LATITUDE;
double LONGITUDE;





@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    u = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);




    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String number = e.getText().toString();
            String loc = t.getText().toString();
            String loc1 = u.getText().toString();
            String loc2 = add.getText().toString();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+number));
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",loc+loc1+loc2);



            try {
                startActivity(sendIntent);
                finish();
                Log.i("Finished sending SMS...", "");
            }
            catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "SMS failed, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            t.append("\n " + location.getLatitude());
            u.append("\n " + location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    configure_button();
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            configure_button();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void configure_button(){
    // first check for permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                    ,10);
        }
        return;
    }
    // this code won't execute IF permissions are not allowed, because in the line above there is return statement.
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps",15000,0, listener);
        }
    });
}

public void phone(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}

    public void address(View view) {

        LATITUDE = Double.parseDouble(t.getText().toString());
        LONGITUDE = Double.parseDouble(u.getText().toString());
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        String result;
        try {

            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i));
                }
                sb.append("\n" + address.getLocality());
                sb.append("\n" + address.getPostalCode());
                sb.append("\n" + address.getCountryName());
                result = sb.toString();
                add.append(result);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending new coordinated to the textView by the following line. 
t.append("\n " + location.getLatitude())

So now when you read the textView t you get all the values separated by \n. Try to split this first so you will get an array of string. Then run a loop converting all the strings to double.

Here is an example of how you can split strings

```
String string = "004-034556";
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
```

Comment: This case would be used if my app was closing due to the numerous values of the coordinates.But even without any values present in the textview the app shuts down if I click the button which implements the reverse geocoder class.

Comment: Hey Thanksss.I got it.I made a really silly mistake.I had written the text "Latitude : " in the textView which I completely forgot about until you emphasized on the strings part.Which led me to realize that I have already written something in the textView....Thankss

Comment: If you found the answer please don't forget to mark it as  right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you put in a class level string array during appending in the textview. So clean and safe code.No risk of null pointer during spliting.

Comment: Thanks for responding :)

Comment: You are welcome. If this one helped you please upvote.